# Unidentified CFRunLoopRun crash report problem

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, wkwebview

I received a lot of crash report about CFRunLoopRun error everyday. It showed up on Xcode and iTunes Connect crash report. However, I did not received any crash reported from user feedback. But I don't know where the error code is. When I opened the error log file for the Xcode project, it just direct to an empty row from swift file.

The app is using WKWebView and Firebase SDK for analysis.

How to fix this crash issue?

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: Namespace SPRINGBOARD, Code 0xdead10cc
Termination Description: SPRINGBOARD, com.xxx.app was task-suspended with locked system files: | /var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/9EAF384F-B017-4E91-BA24-1B9192E31220/database.db | ProcessVisibility: Background | ProcessState: Suspended
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000021c3b9c60 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   CoreFoundation                  0x000000021c7c1e10 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 240 (CFRunLoop.c:2615)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000021c7bcab4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1344 (CFRunLoop.c:2971)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000021c7bc254 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 452 (CFRunLoop.c:3247)
4   GraphicsServices                0x000000021e9fbd8c GSEventRunModal + 108 (GSEvent.c:2245)
5   UIKitCore                       0x0000000249b044c0 UIApplicationMain + 216 (UIApplication.m:4353)
6   Gear                            0x0000000102591a94 main + 68 (BaseTabBarController.swift:14)
7   libdyld.dylib                   0x000000021c278fd8 start + 4

Thread 1 name:
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000021c3b9c60 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   CoreFoundation                  0x000000021c7c1e10 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 240 (CFRunLoop.c:2615)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000021c7bcab4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1344 (CFRunLoop.c:2971)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000021c7bc254 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 452 (CFRunLoop.c:3247)
4   Foundation                      0x000000021d19c04c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304 (NSRunLoop.m:367)
5   Foundation                      0x000000021d19bed4 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 100 (NSRunLoop.m:411)
6   UIKitCore                       0x0000000249bf00d4 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 140 (UIEventFetcher.m:606)
7   Foundation                      0x000000021d19ac4c -[NSThread main] + 72 (NSThread.m:1212)
8   Foundation                      0x000000021d2d0e54 __NSThread__start__ + 988 (NSThread.m:1175)
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000021c43a908 _pthread_body + 132 (pthread.c:857)
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000021c43a864 _pthread_start + 48 (pthread.c:884)
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000021c442dcc thread_start + 4

Thread 2 name:
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000021c3c4ed4 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libc++.1.dylib                  0x000000021b9cc990 std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 28 (__threading_support:278)
2   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000223ae550c void std::__1::condition_variable_any::wait<std::__1::unique_lock<bmalloc::Mutex> >(std::__1::uni... + 104 (condition_variable:204)
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000223ae9560 bmalloc::Scavenger::threadRunLoop() + 172 (condition_variable:213)
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000223ae8cfc bmalloc::Scavenger::threadEntryPoint(bmalloc::Scavenger*) + 16 (Scavenger.cpp:359)
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000223aea724 void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, st... + 44 (type_traits:4345)
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000021c43a908 _pthread_body + 132 (pthread.c:857)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000021c43a864 _pthread_start + 48 (pthread.c:884)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000021c442dcc thread_start + 4

Thread 3 name:
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000021c3b9c60 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   CoreFoundation                  0x000000021c7c1e10 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 240 (CFRunLoop.c:2615)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000021c7bcab4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1344 (CFRunLoop.c:2971)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000021c7bc254 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 452 (CFRunLoop.c:3247)
4   CFNetwork                       0x000000021cdddc88 -[__CoreSchedulingSetRunnable runForever] + 208 (CoreSchedulingSet.mm:1365)
5   Foundation                      0x000000021d19ac4c -[NSThread main] + 72 (NSThread.m:1212)
6   Foundation                      0x000000021d2d0e54 __NSThread__start__ + 988 (NSThread.m:1175)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000021c43a908 _pthread_body + 132 (pthread.c:857)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000021c43a864 _pthread_start + 48 (pthread.c:884)
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000021c442dcc thread_start + 4

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000021c442dc0 start_wqthread + 0 (pthread_dependency.c:103)

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000021c442dc0 start_wqthread + 0 (pthread_dependency.c:103)

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000010004005   x1: 0x0000000007000806   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000c00
    x4: 0x0000000000002a03   x5: 0x00000000ffffffff   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x0000000000000403
    x8: 0x00000000fffffbbf   x9: 0x0000000007000000  x10: 0x0000000007000000  x11: 0x000000b2f51efc80
   x12: 0x00000000016e3600  x13: 0x000000000003757e  x14: 0x000000000004b400  x15: 0x0004b40000000000
   x16: 0xffffffffffffffe1  x17: 0x0000000000000001  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000000
   x20: 0x00000000ffffffff  x21: 0x0000000000002a03  x22: 0x0000000000000c00  x23: 0x000000016d872d30
   x24: 0x0000000007000806  x25: 0x0000000000000000  x26: 0x0000000007000806  x27: 0x0000000000000c00
   x28: 0x0000000000000001   fp: 0x000000016d872c20   lr: 0x000000021c3b90e8
    sp: 0x000000016d872bd0   pc: 0x000000021c3b9c60 cpsr: 0x60000000
```

Comment: It's difficult for me to say actually. Maybe someone more knowledgeable will get back to you. But can you verify if this happens when your app is running? Or when it is backgrounded?

Comment: @jms I tested on my device. There is no crash I can see. And my user also didn't report crash for me. However, this kind of crash report is listed everyday.

Comment: “it just direct to an empty row from swift file.” have you updated the code since the app was released?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson No, there is nothing change for the file (BaseTabBarController.swift) everytime. But it direct to there with the empty row. This file is simple and I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: You apparently have a deadlock accessing your database file. Check your async tasks and whatever kind of async operations you might be doing in javascript. Any script handlers installed? Check your localStorage code if any.

Comment: “The exception code `0xdead10cc` indicates that an application has been terminated by the OS because it held on to a file lock or sqlite database lock during suspension. If your application is performing operations on a locked file or sqlite database at suspension time, it must request additional background execution time to complete those operations and relinquish the lock before suspending.” https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2151/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008184-CH1-EXCEPTION_INFO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, from my limited experience on this matter, it seems like iOS is trying to suspend your application while in background but fails to do so since you have some background process running. Then, since you haven't enabled background processing functionality in your app, iOS force kills it which causes the error to show.

I would advice to look carefully at your app to see for any memory leaks or long running processes. You should fix these issues by tying their usage with the application lifecycle (or consider enabling background processing. Knowledge on ARC, retain cycles and use of capture lists will be important for memory issues).

The locked file indicates something to do with the firebase database. Maybe you are not clearing up connections to the firebase database when your app is backgrounded, etc...

This is all conjecture. Issues like this are quite application specific because you are doing something wrong and you are the best person to identify them since you know your code inside out.

**EDIT:** And I'm also hoping that com.xxx.app is indeed your application and not some other app.

Comment: Thanks. I rechecked the database operation while the app is in background, and find out the place making the database connection is still active, and not close. I solve it and this crash is disappear.